# Why is `ls -al & ; ls -al` invalid?

Tags: linux, bash

I ran this on my Centos5 box:

```
ls -al & ; ls -al
```

I was expecting it to run `ls -al` in the background, and concurrently run `ls -al` in the foreground, and demonstrate how the output to terminal gets all mangled by doing so.

However, I get:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

How can I write these two commands on the same line?

Comment: @thatotherguy I think I've been looking for that website for ... a long time .....!

Comment: @thatotherguy Wow. That's nifty

Comment: Whilst that is a handy site, does not render questions such as this wrong

Comment: You missed a colon in your command.  You could have said: `ls -al & : ; ls -al`.  Emoticons are good.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unintuitively, `&` is a command separator as well as a forker. That means you actually have *three* commands:

```
  ls -al & ; ls -al
# ^^^^^^^|^|^^^^^^^
```

... and Bash does not support the empty statement.

Instead, simply write:

```
  ls -al & ls -al
```

with no semicolon.